# How do I remove case-sensitivity when checking for a string in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, case-sensitive

I'll keep this short and simple. I'm making a chat-based JavaScript game. I have an array called classes:

`const classes = ["brute", "medic", "ranger"];`

And secondly, I have an if statement:

```
if (classes.includes(target)) {
    this.sendReply('Successful.');
} else {
    this.errorReply('"' + target + '"' + ' is not a valid class.');
}
```

So basically, what it should do, is if "target" (which is the name of the class the player types in) types in medic, brute, or ranger as the class, it will return "Successful."

Now, this works, but the problem is that it's case sensitive. For example, if I enter "medic", it will return Successful, but if I type "Medic", it will return "Medic is not a valid class."

How do I remove this case sensitivity? I'd really prefer to not add "medic", "Medic", "ranger", "Ranger", etc etc to the array. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Before checking, turn the string to lowercase, like so:

```
classes.includes(target.toLowerCase())
```

Answer (score 2):

Before you pass the string to your if statement, use the `toLowerCase` method.

```
if (classes.includes(target.toLowerCase())) {
    this.sendReply('Successful.'); 
} else { 
    this.errorReply('"' + target + '"' + ' is not a valid class.');
}
```

Or

```
target = target.toLowerCase();
if (classes.includes(target)) {
    this.sendReply('Successful.'); 
} else { 
    this.errorReply('"' + target + '"' + ' is not a valid class.');
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase

Comment: Please don't reference w3schools, [*MDN*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) and [*ECMA-262*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-string.prototype.tolocalelowercase) are much better.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the string to lowercase before the check

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex with the i flag to ignore case.